# Duplicate tags [string-comparison] and [string-compare]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[string-comparison](/questions/tagged/string-comparison) and [string-compare](/questions/tagged/string-compare) both seem to be about the same concept. The latter has only 20 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken care of - merged and synonymized.